# Navigate the web with the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, websites

I'm trying to learn how to use the terminal, and I want to try sending and receiving data from a common website like Amazon or Google.

I want the terminal to enter a string into a website's search bar and "click" search. I don't need it to open any web pages, just send data to the website as if I had navigated there and typed out the query myself and hit enter.

I'd also like to effectively "check" checkboxes and toggle drop-down search parameters before searching.

In the end I plan on having a set of scripts I can run at any time to long into some of my accounts and toggle settings automatically. Is that secure? Regardless, I want to experiment with navigating websites and returning search results.

This probably involves examining a page's source to decide how to tell it what boxes I've checked or options I've toggled, and perhaps how to handle the returned results.

What terminal commands do I need to know about? What methods should I study?

Answer (score 2):

Try [lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.8/). You won't be disappointed :)

Comment: elinks is my favorite, but lynx is pretty good too

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides complexities in your question:
 1. How to retrieve page source,
 2. How to edit custom data on a parsed HTML page.

The first question is relatively easily achieved through such tools as `wget` or `curl` (see their manuals for more information.

The second question is a bit trivial and really depends on how broadly you want to modify the data. An option is parsing the source of the form and thus building a POST query through `curl --data` option.

On the other hand, current web technologies might offer a lot of trivial techniques to form an object on the browser window, through javascript lazy loading and other. For this you might use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org), which is quite popular among those, who automate for testing developed web pages.